# Prestashop - edit customer Id from backend

Tags: prestashop, custom-controls, backend, edit

Hello everybody I've made an override of Prestashop Customers object form to edit the customer's id from backend. I rendere all the fields with no problem but when I push sabe button it gives me error... I will paste my code below.

```
<?php
    Class AdminCustomersController extends AdminCustomersControllerCore{
        public function renderForm(){
            /** @var Customer $obj */
            if (!($obj = $this->loadObject(true))) {return;}
            $genders = Gender::getGenders();
            $list_genders = array();
            foreach ($genders as $key => $gender) {
                /** @var Gender $gender */
                $list_genders[$key]['id'] = 'gender_'.$gender->id;
                $list_genders[$key]['value'] = $gender->id;
                $list_genders[$key]['label'] = $gender->name;
            }
            $years = Tools::dateYears();
            $months = Tools::dateMonths();
            $days = Tools::dateDays();
            $groups = Group::getGroups($this->default_form_language, true);
            $this->fields_form = array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Customer'),
                    'icon' => 'icon-user'
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text', // id_customer field to edit 
                        'label' => $this->l('Codice cliente'),
                        'name' => 'id_customer',
                        'size' => 64,
                        'col' => '4'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'radio',
                        'label' => $this->l('Social title'),
                        'name' => 'id_gender',
                        'required' => false,
                        'class' => 't',
                        'values' => $list_genders
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('First name'),
                        'name' => 'firstname',
                        'required' => true,
                        'col' => '4',
                        'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' 0-9!&lt;&gt;,;?=+()@#"°{}_$%:'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('Last name'),
                        'name' => 'lastname',
                        'required' => true,
                        'col' => '4',
                        'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' 0-9!&lt;&gt;,;?=+()@#"°{}_$%:'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('Codice cliente Target:'),
                        'name' => 'codice_target',
                        'size' => 64,
                        'col' => '4'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('Company'),
                        'name' => 'company',
                        'required' => true,
                        'col' => '4',
                        'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' 0-9!&lt;&gt;,;?=+()@#"°{}_$%:'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('P.iva'),
                        'name' => 'vat_number',
                        'required' => true,
                        'col' => '4',
                        'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' 0-9!&lt;&gt;,;?=+()@#"°{}_$%:'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'prefix' => '<i class="icon-envelope-o"></i>',
                        'label' => $this->l('Email address'),
                        'name' => 'email',
                        'col' => '4',
                        'required' => true,
                        'autocomplete' => false
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'password',
                        'label' => $this->l('Password'),
                        'name' => 'passwd',
                        'required' => ($obj->id ? false : true),
                        'col' => '4',
                        'hint' => ($obj->id ? $this->l('Leave this field blank if there\'s no change.') :
                            sprintf($this->l('Password should be at least %s characters long.'), Validate::PASSWORD_LENGTH))
                    ),
                    /*array(
                        'type' => 'birthday',
                        'label' => $this->l('Birthday'),
                        'name' => 'birthday',
                        'options' => array(
                            'days' => $days,
                            'months' => $months,
                            'years' => $years
                        )
                    ),*/
                    array(
                        'type' => 'switch',
                        'label' => $this->l('Enabled'),
                        'name' => 'active',
                        'required' => false,
                        'class' => 't',
                        'is_bool' => true,
                        'values' => array(
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_on',
                                'value' => 1,
                                'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'id' => 'active_off',
                                'value' => 0,
                                'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
                            )
                        ),
                        'hint' => $this->l('Enable or disable customer login.')
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'switch',
                        'label' => $this->l('Newsletter'),
                        'name' => 'newsletter',
                        'required' => false,
                        'class' => 't',
                        'is_bool' => true,
                        'values' => array(
                            array(
                                'id' => 'newsletter_on',
                                'value' => 1,
                                'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'id' => 'newsletter_off',
                                'value' => 0,
                                'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
                            )
                        ),
                        'disabled' =>  (bool)!Configuration::get('PS_CUSTOMER_NWSL'),
                        'hint' => $this->l('This customer will receive your newsletter via email.')
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'switch',
                        'label' => $this->l('Opt-in'),
                        'name' => 'optin',
                        'required' => false,
                        'class' => 't',
                        'is_bool' => true,
                        'values' => array(
                            array(
                                'id' => 'optin_on',
                                'value' => 1,
                                'label' => $this->l('Enabled')
                            ),
                            array(
                                'id' => 'optin_off',
                                'value' => 0,
                                'label' => $this->l('Disabled')
                            )
                        ),
                        'disabled' =>  (bool)!Configuration::get('PS_CUSTOMER_OPTIN'),
                        'hint' => $this->l('This customer will receive your ads via email.')
                    ),
                )
            );
            // if we add a customer via fancybox (ajax), it's a customer and he doesn't need to be added to the visitor and guest groups
            if(Tools::isSubmit('addcustomer') && Tools::isSubmit('submitFormAjax')){
                $visitor_group = Configuration::get('PS_UNIDENTIFIED_GROUP');
                $guest_group = Configuration::get('PS_GUEST_GROUP');
                foreach ($groups as $key => $g) {
                    if (in_array($g['id_group'], array($visitor_group, $guest_group))) {
                        unset($groups[$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
            $this->fields_form['input'] = array_merge(
                $this->fields_form['input'],
                array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'group',
                        'label' => $this->l('Group access'),
                        'name' => 'groupBox',
                        'values' => $groups,
                        'required' => true,
                        'col' => '6',
                        'hint' => $this->l('Select all the groups that you would like to apply to this customer.')
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'label' => $this->l('Default customer group'),
                        'name' => 'id_default_group',
                        'options' => array(
                            'query' => $groups,
                            'id' => 'id_group',
                            'name' => 'name'
                        ),
                        'col' => '4',
                        'hint' => array(
                            $this->l('This group will be the user\'s default group.'),
                            $this->l('Only the discount for the selected group will be applied to this customer.')
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
            // if customer is a guest customer, password hasn't to be there
            if ($obj->id && ($obj->is_guest && $obj->id_default_group == Configuration::get('PS_GUEST_GROUP'))) {
                foreach ($this->fields_form['input'] as $k => $field) {
                    if ($field['type'] == 'password') {
                        array_splice($this->fields_form['input'], $k, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(Configuration::get('PS_B2B_ENABLE')) {
                $risks = Risk::getRisks();
                $list_risks = array();
                foreach ($risks as $key => $risk) {
                    /** @var Risk $risk */
                    $list_risks[$key]['id_risk'] = (int)$risk->id;
                    $list_risks[$key]['name'] = $risk->name;
                }
                $this->fields_form['input'][] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Company'),
                    'name' => 'company'
                );
                $this->fields_form['input'][] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('SIRET'),
                    'name' => 'siret'
                );
                $this->fields_form['input'][] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('APE'),
                    'name' => 'ape'
                );
                $this->fields_form['input'][] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Website'),
                    'name' => 'website'
                );
                $this->fields_form['input'][] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Allowed outstanding amount'),
                    'name' => 'outstanding_allow_amount',
                    'hint' => $this->l('Valid characters:').' 0-9',
                    'suffix' => $this->context->currency->sign
                );
                $this->fields_form['input'][] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Maximum number of payment days'),
                    'name' => 'max_payment_days',
                    'hint' => $this->l('Valid characters:').' 0-9'
                );
                $this->fields_form['input'][] = array(
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'label' => $this->l('Risk rating'),
                    'name' => 'id_risk',
                    'required' => false,
                    'class' => 't',
                    'options' => array(
                        'query' => $list_risks,
                        'id' => 'id_risk',
                        'name' => 'name'
                    ),
                );
            }
            $this->fields_form['submit'] = array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            );
            $birthday = explode('-', $this->getFieldValue($obj, 'birthday'));
            $this->fields_value = array(
                'years' => $this->getFieldValue($obj, 'birthday') ? $birthday[0] : 0,
                'months' => $this->getFieldValue($obj, 'birthday') ? $birthday[1] : 0,
                'days' => $this->getFieldValue($obj, 'birthday') ? $birthday[2] : 0,
            );
            // Added values of object Group
            if (!Validate::isUnsignedId($obj->id)) {
                $customer_groups = array();
            }
            else {
                $customer_groups = $obj->getGroups();
            }
            $customer_groups_ids = array();
            if (is_array($customer_groups)) {
                foreach ($customer_groups as $customer_group) {
                    $customer_groups_ids[] = $customer_group;
                }
            }
            // if empty $carrier_groups_ids : object creation : we set the default groups
            if (empty($customer_groups_ids)) {
                $preselected = array(
                    Configuration::get('PS_UNIDENTIFIED_GROUP'),
                    Configuration::get('PS_GUEST_GROUP'),
                    Configuration::get('PS_CUSTOMER_GROUP')
                );
                $customer_groups_ids = array_merge($customer_groups_ids, $preselected);
            }
            foreach ($groups as $group) {
                $this->fields_value['groupBox_'.$group['id_group']] = Tools::getValue('groupBox_'.$group['id_group'], in_array($group['id_group'], $customer_groups_ids));
            }
            return AdminController::renderForm();
        }
    }
?>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you give us the error throwed in the backoffice ?

Comment: 2 errori

    Oggetto impossibile da caricare (o non trovato)
    Si è verificato un errore durante il caricamento dell'oggetto. customer (Impossibile caricare l'oggetto)

Comment: 2 errors

     Object impossible to load (or not found)
     There was an error loading the object. customer (Can not load the object)